How to use windows Authentication in Uipath CLI?
Is possible to use WinAuth in Uipath CLI?
I try with User and password and i get an error:
Could not connect to Orchestrator: [...] , Tenant: [...], Username: [...], Password: ***, OrganizationUnit: [...], UseWindowsCredentials: False.

I try to read docs and help but i didn't find reference about how to set option "UseWindowsCredentials" to true
